# React Native fix for iOS zoom mode

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native, layout

Is there a way to disable layout scaling when the user enables zoom mode on iOS? Something like allowFontScaling={false} for dynamic font scaling, or anything similar? When the user enables that mode, the whole layout is messed up and zoomed in, for example, the text is not fitting in where it should in standard mode.

Comment: Would like to know any best practices for this as well.

Comment: still no update on it?